# Android using kSoap with webservices other than .NET

Tags: android, progress, ksoap2

I'm trying to make an application that's making a connection to an XML-page that I've built with Progress database. I've tried accessing it with kSoap2, following this tutorial (http://seesharpgears.blogspot.com/2010/10/web-service-that-returns-array-of.html).

It doesn't really go into my Progress Procedure, so I don't get any response, so I'm wondering if this kSoap actually works with other webservices than .NET webservices?

You can find my webservice class over here http://pastebin.com/50rhLCFr.
My domain class is built exactly like the tutorial and the Progresscode works if I save the file to XML.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please post some code that you have tried.

Comment: I have edited my question with my code.

Comment: Please look at this link:- http://pastebin.com/2VjcG9b3 and tell me if its working fine or not.

Comment: I've tried your code, but it still crashes. I think my problem is not exactly with kSoap, but with calling a Progress Procedure outside of Progress. I want to thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with a number of web services alongside android and this is my usual debugging process:

1. Build up a request manually and POST it using some software such as SoapUI to verify it works
2. once you have successfully constructed a working request you can then simply HTTP POST it from within android
3. store your own request templates and fill them out using string replace

this technique avoids using Ksoap, which I have found to be quite annoying!